# How to install Rapidminer Studio on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, java

I tried to install Rapidminer studio on my Ubuntu 18.04 From the .zip file
I followed the instructions in [Installing RapidMiner Studio](https://docs.rapidminer.com/latest/studio/installation/). I applied the command `./RapidMiner-Studio.sh` and got:

```
RAPIDMINER_HOME is not set. Trying the directory '/home/user/snap/Rapidminer/rapidminer-studio'...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at com.rapidminer.license.verification.JarVerifier.createPublicKey(JarVerifier.java:267)
    at com.rapidminer.license.verification.JarVerifier.<clinit>(JarVerifier.java:137)
    at com.rapidminer.launcher.GUILauncher.main(GUILauncher.java:286)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Use openjdk-8. Rapidminer runs on only openjdk 8 so if you have java 11 installed change preferences to openjdk-8.